# Convert folder symlink to a regular folder

Tags: bash, symbolic-link

I have a folder symlink and I want to replace the symlink by its content (clone symlink content to a folder named as the symlink and remove the symlink).

Is there any simple command to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no direct filesystem command to do that, so maybe the easiest way to do covert the `myDir` symlink to a regular folder is:

```
cp -Lr myDir myDir-COPY &&
rm myDir &&
mv myDir-COPY myDir
```